# R h2o getHelpFile: package 'XYZ' exists but was not installed under R >= ver.num so help cannot be accessed

Tags: r, linux, installation, h2o

I am running on a Linux system; R v3.3.2; H2O v3.10.2.1.

I installed H2O v3.10.2.1 via:

```
install.packages( "h2o", type="source", 
  repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tutte/1/R")))
```

During installation, I saw a few warning messages, for example:

```
Rd warning: /tmp/Rtmp2c0lfT/R.INSTALL13f787112f6e2/h2o/man/use.package.Rd:24: file link ‘fwrite’ in package ‘data.table’ does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
```

I am now unable to access help:

```
> ?h2o.init
Error in .getHelpFile(file) : 
  package ‘h2o_v3.10.2.1’ exists but was not installed under R >= 2.10.0 so help cannot be accessed

> help(h2o.init)
Error in .getHelpFile(file) : 
  package ‘h2o_v3.10.2.1’ exists but was not installed under R >= 2.10.0 so help cannot be accessed
```

Because I needed to find a version of H2O that worked around an issue I have in one of my R/H2O scripts, I installed many versions of H2O.  My `.libPaths()` directory looks like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x 10 userme 4.0K Apr 17 13:10 dplyr
drwxrwxr-x  6 userme  107 Apr 17 13:10 dtplyr
lrwxrwxrwx  1 userme   13 May  3 10:13 h2o -> h2o_v3.10.2.1
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K Apr 11 07:43 h2o_v3.10.0.8
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K Apr 11 20:00 h2o_v3.10.2.1
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K Apr 11 19:05 h2o_v3.10.3.1
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K Apr 11 11:52 h2o_v3.10.3.2
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K Apr 10 13:38 h2o_v3.10.3.5
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K Apr 11 10:24 h2o_v3.10.4.3
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K Apr 11 08:59 h2o_v3.11.0.3839
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K May  3 08:48 h2o_v3.6.0.8
drwxrwxr-x  9 userme 4.0K Apr 10 20:58 h2o_v3.8.1.4
drwxrwxr-x 16 userme 4.0K Apr 17 13:05 Rcpp
```

Where `h2o` is a symbolic link to a specific directory.

What do I need to do to get these help files?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using RStudio, by chance?  I've seen docs get corrupted, but fixed after a restart of RStudio.  Also, why are you trying to install an old version of the **h2o** R package?  Can you `remove.packages("h2o")` and then `install.packages("h2o")` to get the latest version?

Comment: No, I am not using RStudio.  I am running an older version of H2O to work around a bug.

Comment: What's the bug?  Are you saying there is a bug in a new version of H2O that did not exist in an older version?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a bug.  Perhaps the way I installed this older version of H2O did not install the `?/help()` documentation?  ```install.packages( "h2o", type="source", 
  repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tutte/1/R")))
 ```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `remove.packages("h2o")` and remove all those `h2o` directories in your `.libPaths()` folder.  The symlink may work, but just to rule that out, I'd remove it.

Then reinstall **h2o** 3.10.2.1 using the same method above:

```
install.packages( "h2o", type="source", 
   repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tutte/1/R")))
```

If that doesn't work, then download **h2o** 3.10.2.1 from S3 or 3.10.2.2 from CRAN:

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/rel-tutte/1/R/src/contrib/h2o_3.10.2.1.tar.gz
- https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/h2o/h2o_3.10.2.2.tar.gz

Install via:  `R CMD INSTALL h2o_3.10.2.1.tar.gz`